# Отрицательные числа и СС

Tags: числа, системы-счисления

Известно, что с помощью одного байта можно представить максимум число 255. Погуглил что происходит с отрицательными числами. Столкнулся с понятиями прямого и дополнительного кода. С этим всё понятно, прямой в качестве знака использует старший разряд, 0 - положительное, 1 - отрицательное, при этом диапазон уменьшается до [-128, 127] и используется для полож. чисел, ну а доп. код с ещё некоторыми операциями составляется для отрицательных. Но почему нам говорят про то, что одним байтом можно представит максимум 255, если получается не 255, а 127?

Comment: Ну так для беззнаковых чисел от 0 до 255, а для знаковых от -128 до 127. Все зависит от того, как интерпретировать содержимое этого байта.

Comment: @tilin а как процессору понять какое это число, знаковое или беззнаковое, когда старший разряд это знак, а когда нет?

Comment: Для этого в языках программирования есть знаковые и беззнаковые типы данных. Например в С есть char, а есть unsigned char

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко т.е. у процессора просто есть разграничение между знаковыми и беззнаковыми типами данных, а язык программирования просто сортирует наши числа между этими двумя типа для процессора?

Comment: А процессору на самом деле фиолетово. для этого и придуман дополнительный код. арифметические операции  работают просто с байтом, как будто никакого знака нет вовсе. Их результат в двоичном виде всегда одинаков вне зависимости от того знаковое было число или нет. Но вот тот результат, что получился может быть интерпретирован и как знаковое и как беззнаковое, в зависимости от желания программиста. Единственное где для процессора есть некоторая разница - это операции сравнения, для этого существуют отдельные операции переходов, которые немного по разному интерпретируют флаги переполнения.

Comment: Ну например, в случае сложения или вычитания процессору вообще пофиг есть знак или нет, а вот для умножения и деления там немного разные действия

Comment: @Mike т.е. я правильно понял, что язык программирования сам переделывает число под процессор так, чтобы ему нужно было выполнить просто сложение к пример. Но то что он вернёт будет например 11001100 мы можем для себя определять как знаковое и тогда оно будет отрицательным, а может определить для себя как обычное беззнаковое 204?

Comment: В общем да, только что вы называете "язык переделывает" ? если вы в программе пишите число например в десятичном виде 204, то язык конечно в программе положит в это место байт с указанным вами двоичным значением, т.е. просто произведет перевод системы счисления. Если вы указали отрицательное число, то запишет его в дополнительном коде. Ну плюс к этому, как правильно заметил @НикитаВасильченко, в зависимости от того какой тип данных предполагается операцию скажем умножения сформирует как MUL (без знака) или IMUL (со знаком)

Comment: @Mike под сформирует как знаковое или беззнаковое предполагается, что числа определёнными действиями переведутся в такой вид, чтобы процессор своими обычными действиями вернул правильный ответ? Но при этом, если скажем так язык отметил это место, как место где используется знаковое число, то и ответ будет знаковым и интерпретирует он его тоже как знаковое?

Comment: В один байт можно записать не более 256 различных значений. Какое число какому значению будет соответствовать - тот еще вопрос...

Comment: ответ будет просто набор байт. А вот как их интерпретировать, скажем при выводе на экран - это уже дело программы

Comment: @ProstoCoder Вот скажем ваше число 11001100, со знаком оно -52, без знака 204. Предположим нам надо прибавить к этому числу 1. в двоичном виде получится 11001101. Если этот результат рассматривать как беззнаковый то будет 205, а если как знаковый то -51 Как видите процессору вообще думать не надо что это за число, за счет использования дополнительного кода все произошло само собой.

Comment: @Mike в общем процессор выполняет свои элементарные операции с 0 и 1, а программа совместно с языком программирования  крутит этими 0 и 1 так, чтобы мы получали то, что должны получить

Comment: @ProstoCoder Ну в общем виде да. только если язык программирования - ассемблер, вы сами принимаете решение какую инструкцию использовать в тех случаях когда нужное действие по разному выполняется для знаковых и беззнаковых.

Comment: @Mike понятно, спасибо

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко понятно, я так понимаю что всё же процессору тоже пофиг и на деление с умножением, париться приходится программе